# How can I import PCL into Python, on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, point-cloud-library, ros

So my situation is as follows: I am on an Ubuntu 14.04, and I am very simply, trying to use PCL (point cloud library) in Python 2.7x.

I followed the instructions here,(http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html), however in Python if I now do

> import pcl

I still get the error:

> ImportError: No module named pcl

I am not sure what else to do - there do not seem to be any more leads I can follow... thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [python-pcl](https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl).
It is a python binding and supports operations on PointXYZ.